# Burning atomic elements

Tags: atoms, heat-engine, elements

when someone says "the carbon was completely burnt up" eg. in a car's engine. what does that mean?, Where does it go? I know no new elements are formed and of course it really didn't  disappeared. so what is happening?

Comment: Who are "they?"  Are they talking about carbon _deposits_ (a.k.a., "[soot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soot)")?  Soot burns by combining with oxygen to form [carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) and [carbon monoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide).

Comment: The expression is "blow the carbon out". If your engine is running lean you can get incomplete combustion and over a long period this can build up as carbon on the cylinder heads and spark plugs. When you blow the carbon out you take your ride out on an open highway and floor the engine to get the rpm's higher than you normally would driving city streets. The higher speed increases heat and temperature causing any carbon in the cylinders to burn thus creating CO and CO2, which can then make their way out the exhaust. But always drive safe and obey the traffic laws.

Answer (score 0):

This is I think to do with chemistry...., but here goes....

In a car the fuel is generally a hydrocarbon mixture - a mixture of compounds with H and C atoms - lets call it H$_x$C$_y$ for short....

Now in complete combustion

${\rm H}_x{\rm C}_y + (y+x/4){\rm O}_2 \rightarrow (x/2) {\rm H}_2{\rm O} + y {\rm CO}_2 $

In this case all the atomic carbon is 'burnt up'.

But if the quantity of oxygen not sufficient for complete burning then we can get either

${\rm H}_x{\rm C}_y + (y/2+x/4){\rm O}_2 \rightarrow (x/2) {\rm H}_2{\rm O} + y {\rm CO} $

or

${\rm H}_x{\rm C}_y + (x/4){\rm O}_2 \rightarrow (x/2) {\rm H}_2{\rm O} + y {\rm C} $

So in the first case of incomplete burning we get CO, carbon monoxide formed. In the second case we get C, atomic carbon formed..

And there may be some situations where some fuel or partially burnt hydrocarbon molecules also go into the exhaust.

So I think the answer to your question is that if all the atomic carbon is burnt in an engine then all the carbon is converted to at least carbon monoxide (CO) or more likely carbon dioxide (CO$_2$)